# Exclude 7 inch Tablets below Android 3.2 in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

Even after a lot of research and work and I have been unable to implement the UI of my app on 7" tablets below 3.2.

Is it possible to exclude that group of devices with the manifest?

I've found that you can exclude by size and by android version but not both together.

Comment: Have you considered publishing [Multiple APKs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the devices on Google Play by screen size and some other option
http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

I don't think that you can exclude devices in the manifest.